# How to add customized line numbers into a file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to append `file2` to `file1`. Before I do that, I need add customized line number to the `file2`.

`file1`

```
1 abc
2 bcd
3 efg
```

`file2`

```
mkh
dfd
aad
```

1. Add line number into `file2` following `file1`.

   ```
   4 mkh
   5 dfd    
   6 aad
   ```
2. Append `file2` to `file1`

   ```
   cat file2 >> file1
   ```

How can I add line number into `file2` shown above?

Comment: Ah, I misread this at first.  I see now that `file1` *already* includes line numbers, which is why you can't just use `cat file1 file2 | nl > newfile; mv newfile file1`.  In that case, good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nl -v "$((1+$(wc -l < file1)))" file2 >> file1
```

`nl` is a tool to **n**umber **l**ines of a file.  The `-v` switch provides the starting value of the line numbers.  I use a subshell and `wc` to get a line count of `file1`, and add one to it to get the starting line number for `file2`, and concatenate the results onto the end of `file1`.

Note that `wc -l file1` would print the line count followed by the filename, but since we've redirected `wc`'s stdin to come from `file1`, the `wc` tool itself doesn't know anything about the filename for `file1` and just prints the line count only (with some whitespace that doesn't matter in this context).

---

This can be done *slightly* more cleanly just using `awk` and `nl`:

```
nl -v $(awk 'END { print NR + 1 }' file1) file2 >> file1
```

Comment: I've made a simplification, but both the old and the new versions of this code will have leading whitespace rather than the no-leading-whitespace form of line numbers shown in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works well. I improved it based on my job demand.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk -v nl=$(wc -l <f1.txt) '{print NR+nl " " $0}' f2.txt
```

- `$(wc -l <f1.txt)` gets the number of lines in file `f1.txt`, we are passing this as `nl` variable into `awk`
- `print NR+nl " " $0` prints each record of `f2.txt` with corresponding line number added to variable `nl`, then a space, and then the whole record

**Example:**

```
% cat f1.txt 
1 abc
2 bcd
3 efg

% cat f2.txt 
mkh
dfd
aad

% awk -v nl=$(wc -l <f1.txt) '{print NR+nl " " $0}' f2.txt
4 mkh
5 dfd
6 aad
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` solution:

```
$ awk 'NF==1{print ++c" "$1 >> "file1"} NF>1{c=$1}' file1 file2
$ cat file1
1 abc
2 bcd
3 efg
4 mkh
5 dfd
6 aad
```

Generic case:

```
$ cat file1
1 abc x
2 bcd y
3 efg z
$ cat file2
mkh 1a
dfd foo
aad bar

$ awk 'NR==FNR{c=$1; next} {print ++c" "$0 >> "file1"}' file1 file2
$ cat file1
1 abc x
2 bcd y
3 efg z
4 mkh 1a
5 dfd foo
6 aad bar
```

Comment: I doubt that the OP’s real file2 is actually `mkh` / `dfd` / `aad`.   I would assume that he gave that example to illustrate that file2 doesn’t have line numbers.   I doubt that it’s valid to interpret that example as a statement that every line in file2 has exactly one word.

Comment: @Scott fair enough, I have added a solution for that case

Answer (score 0):

A very simple answer:

```
$ cat testText 
1. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

$ cat testText | tr ' ' '\n' | sort >testText2

$ cat -n testText testText2
     1  1. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
     2  1.
     3  brown
     4  dog.
     5  fox
     6  jumped
     7  lazy
     8  over
     9  quick
    10  the
    11  The
```

Comment: Assuming the INITIAL files without line numbers. Removing the leading blanks is a simple thing using sed, left as an exercise for the user.